# friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.1.0 conflicts with sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v2.2.6]

Tags: web-services, symfony, composer-php

Hi my application is running with Symfony 2.2, I am trying to install FOSRESTBundle with commannde `composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle` for this purpose but I am getting the following error.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Problem 1
- friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.1.0 conflicts with sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v2.2.6].
- friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.1.0 conflicts with sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v2.2.6].
- friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.1.0 conflicts with sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v2.2.6].
- Installation request for friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle ^2.1 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[2.1.0].
- Installation request for sensio/framework-extra-bundle (locked at v2.2.6, required as 2.2.*) -> satisfiable by sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v2.2.6].Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

the content of composer.json is here

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "winzou/console-bundle": "1.*",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.x-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures" : "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
        "ornicar/akismet-bundle": "dev-master",
        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "spraed/pdf-generator-bundle": "^1.2",
        "psliwa/pdf-bundle": "^1.0",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.3",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "0.12.2.1",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-i386": "0.12.2.1",
        "obtao/html2pdf-bundle": "master-dev"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have symfony2.2 please try:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle:1.5.3
```

Or update symfony.

Comment: thanks it was istalled, but jms/serializer-bundle can't installed with composer require jms/serializer-bundle:1.5.3 ?

Comment: composer require jms/serializer:0.12.0

You can check available version at:
https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle

Comment: thanks, I want to create rest webservice with symfony2, how I can do this ?

Comment: symfony2/3 + fractal